# Laravel - file required validation vice versa

Tags: php, validation, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

Ok, this problem is quite hilarious, but i need to solve it:

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and making a form to upload a picture. I have this rules:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'picture ' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    'description' => 'required'
);
```

The description validation is ok, but when validating the picture, the 'required' attribute seems to work vice versa - when a file (picture) is selected, then it fails to validate (error: 'The picture field is required') and when there is no file, the validation succeeds.

Here is the code from my controller:

```
    Log::info('Validating store picture request');

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Picture::$rules);

    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        Log::info('After method');
        // check for validity of the file
        if (!Input::file('picture')->isValid()) {
            Log::info('Picture is not valid');
            $validator->errors()->add('picture', 'Picture is not valid');
        }
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Log::info('Validation failed, returning back');

        $messages = $validator->messages();
        return back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('picture'));
    }
    Log::info('Validation succeed, continuing');
```

EDIT: I did logging of the Validator class this way:

```
protected function validateRequired($attribute, $value)
{
    Log::info('Just logging required validation');
    Log::info('is_null: '.is_null($value));

    if (is_null($value)) {
        Log::info('Reason: is_null');
        return false;
    } elseif (is_string($value) && trim($value) === '') {
        return false;
    } elseif ((is_array($value) || $value instanceof Countable) && count($value) < 1) {
        return false;
    } elseif ($value instanceof File) {
        Log::info('File, getpath '.$value->getPath());
        return (string) $value->getPath() != '';
    }

    Log::info('Continuing');
    return true;
}
```

and this is what i get when submitting the form **with a file**:

```
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Validating store picture request  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Just logging required validation  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: is_null: 1  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Reason: is_null  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Just logging required validation  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: is_null: 1  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Reason: is_null  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: After method  
[2016-08-15 12:18:27] local.INFO: Validation failed, returning back
```

EDIT: the same log output i get, when there is no file, so now it's behaving the same way.. and I don't know why it's performed twice per one requeset :/

Comment: Its so weird. What about enctype property on the <form>

Comment: There is 'multipart/form-data' - the uploading and storing of picture works ok (when missing the validation)

Comment: I faced same problem before. You can try other validate rule. Like "image" or "mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png"

Comment: use `required|file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png`

Comment: Are you sure this is Laravel 5.2?

Comment: @KmasterYC - doesn't solve if there is no file

Comment: @jaysingkar still the same

Comment: @MinaAbadir Yes, this is Laravel 5.2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed, in your rules array you have a space in `pictures` key.
I tried to check, if that spaces causes any error. And yes it does fail the validation. Thought, I think this should not cause the error.

Try removing that space.

```
public static $rules = array(
    'picture' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', //Remove space from 'picture'
    'description' => 'required'
);
```

Comment: thank you, now it works OK :) i really didn't notice that.. :D But even though, the behavior was quite strange :/